# Android volley : how to check json type before parsing it

Tags: android, json, types, android-volley

Is it possible to check the type of json beforehand? I'm somteimes getting an array and sometimes an object and I don't see how to handle these 2 cases without doing 2 different functions...

```
public void RequestApi( String url, final ApiResponse<ApiResult> completion  )
    {
        Log.v("Performing request: ", url);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, hostname+url, (JSONObject) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    Log.v("RequestApi Response", response.toString());
                    //Log.v("Data: ", response.toString());
                    try {
                        ApiResult res = new ApiResult();
                        Boolean success = response.getBoolean("success");

                        //here need to check type, sometimes array, sometimes object
                        JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data"); 

                        res.success = success;
                        res.data = data;
                        completion.onCompletion(res);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    ApiResult res = new ApiResult();
                    res.success = false;
                    completion.onCompletion(res);
                }
            }
        );

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);
    }
```

Comment: #kali can u show the both json

Comment: Are you getting JsonArray in response of JsonObjectRequest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple solution - look at first string character. If it is `{` - object, if `[` - array. But I think better to do following:

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(value);
}
catch (JSONException) {
    //if it throws, "value" contains not a JSONObject
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(value);
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if this is the right option... might work for some cases...

Answer (score 6):

Use [StringRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple)

```
  // Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
       Object json = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
       if (json instanceof JSONObject)
         //you have an object
       else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
       //you have an array
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through the API I found a simple solution.
Since you are not sure of the return type, follow mentioned below steps.

First:

```
JSONArray arrayInstance = new JSONArray();// declare array instance to handle both the cases 
Object objectInstance = rootObject.get(key); //key is the response string holding the value either jsonArray or jsonObject
```

Second:

```
if(objectInstance instanceof JSONArray){
       arrayInstance = rootObject.getJSONArray(key);
    }

else{
        JSONObject tempObject = rootObject.getJSONObject(key);
        arrayInstance.put(tempObject);
    }
```

Third: 
You can iterate though the array for the desired processing.